# Add ComboBox Items from txt file

Tags: c++, forms, file, combobox

I have .txt file with some string.

When I loading data from a file into arrays I want to add data into comboBox.
But when I try it, all information supplied only one field.(look on screen)

I want to make each new line from file a new field in comboBox1.

My code:

```
public: System::Void mainBase()
{
string fileName = "mainBase/main.txt";
fstream f;

char str[20][255];
int count=0;
char tmp[255];

f.open(fileName, ios::in);

if(!f)
    label2->Text = "error file";



while(f.getline(tmp, 255,'\0'))  {  

            //strncpy(str[count++],tmp,255);
    //Object^ myObj = gcnew Object();

            System::String^ myString = gcnew String(tmp);

            //myObj = myString;

            this->comboBox1->Items->Add(myString);
}

/*for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{

}*/

f.close();
}
```

I call method in constructor.
Screen: http://postimg.org/image/g6s23pac9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
while(f.getline(tmp, 255,'\0')) {
```

With:

```
while(f.getline(tmp, 255,'\n'))  {
```

'\n' is the newline character, not '\0' (which is end of string I think)